# javascript replaceWith + classid

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, class, this

Seems I'm getting a bit of a problem and I'm pretty confused what for..

The code:

```
$(".post-click").click(function()
{
    var classid = $(this).attr('id');
    var postid = $(this).attr('id');
    postid = postid.replace('post-click-id_', '');

    alert("ID: " + classid + " PostID: " + postid);

    $(this).replaceWith('<img SRC="assets/img/refresh.gif" ALT="" id="' + classid + '">');

    $.post("likepost.php", { postid: postid } , function(data)
    {
        $(document).foundationTooltips();

        alert(data);
            $("#" + classid).replaceWith(data);

            var classes = $("#" + classid).attr('class');

            alert(classes);
    });
});
```

Now, what this does it, when you click on it, it replaces the text of the ID you clicked on. Now, on top I got this:

```
$(".post-click").click(function()
{
```

It seems post-click doesn't get called anymore after the replacement. To be sure I replaced it with the good class, I putted the 'var classes = ...' out there. It alerts that the class post-click is in the replacement.

Replacement is:
   < a class="post-click" href="#" >test< /a >";

Any ideas why jQuery doesn't call the post-click anymore?

Comment: What do you mean by "..doesn't get called anymore after the replacement."? Doesn't get called when you click it again? You're replacing the whole element with `$(this).replaceWith('<img SRC="assets/img/refresh.gif" ALT="" >');`

Answer (score 2):

When using `replaceWith`, you are replacing the DOM element, complete with its event bindings.

Luckily, jQuery provides `.on` which allows you to use event delegation (as opposed to looping through the new content rebinding your events).

You apply it to a parent node of post-click and then specify the class in the arguments.

e.g.

```
$(".some-parent-elem").on("click", ".post-click", 
       function (){...do stuff on click...});
```

How this works is that it listens for clicks on .some-parent-elem (which due to event bubbling will mean it fires when you click on a child of that element) and then if the original target element that was clicked has the class of post-click, it runs the function.